# Package Filter in Logback.xml

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, logback

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBTp6.png)

I would like to output log for all queries under every mapper package.
I don't want like to define each mapper package like this since the project will consist of a lot of packages later.

[don't want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoj6b.png)

How can i achieve like this?

```
<logger name="com.example.demo.*.mapper" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a String constant for the logger name instead of letting Logback derive the logger name from the current class. For example, each class in the `com.example.demo.*.mapper` package would declare a logger like so:

```
// extract "MAPPER" to a shared constant to maybe provide a MapperLogger utility class 
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MAPPER");
```

Then your logger configuration would be:

```
<logger name="MAPPER" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SAVE-TO-FILE" />
</logger>
```

Or you could programmatically create loggers for every class in the `com.example.demo.*.mapper` package and associate each with your `SAVE-TO-FILE` appender.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an answer to that question. That is why I've done some filtering by myself using `ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter`:

```
<configuration>
    <property name="package" value="com.example.demo.*.mapper" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>return logger.matches("^" + "${package}".replaceAll("\\*", "\\.*").replaceAll("([^\\\\])\\.", "$1\\\\.") + "$");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
            <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level [%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%thread] %-30logger{10} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```